# QuickFIX/n - Incorrect handling of SequenceRest Gap Fill message

Tags: quickfix

While performing a message recovery operation in chunks of 2500 messages per resend request,
drop copy gap fills the administrative messages.

Assuming sending "resend request’s” from 10260 till 36264.

```
1st resend request 10260 till 12759
2nd resend request 12760 till 15259
3rd resend request 15260 till 17759
4th resend request 17760 till 20259
```

And so on……

While responding the 3rd resend request,
                the counter party sends the SequenceReset as there was a gap fill for administrative messages.
                However the NewSequence number in that SequenceReset is 36265 (that is actually greater than 3rd resend request end sequence no 17759).

And then QUICK FIX ignores the next expected resend request itself i.e., 4th  resend request 17760 till 20259

How should we handle this scenario as such to send the 4th resend request when there is a gapfill towards the end of the resend request response?

Please advice.

Comment: In your first sentence, what do you mean by _drop copy gap fills the administrative messages_?

Comment: i mean the "counter party gap fills the administrative messages"

Comment: I suspect there is an error in QuickFIX/N. In any case, if you report this problem it is crucial to have an exact trace of what FIX messages were sent (in both directions). I see you reported it [here](https://github.com/connamara/quickfixn/issues/309) but without an exact trace of all FIX messages you won't get much followup on the issue I'm afraid. Check your FIX logs for an exact trace of the FIX messages and add them to your bug-report. From the help page [bug](http://www.quickfixn.org/help): _Please provide sample code, logs, and a description of the problem when the issue is submitted._